# Xamarin Studio do not start after install

Tags: xamarin

Trying to install and run Xamarin Studio on my Mac, unfortunately this is not going well, please help. I have 7 years cross platform and app development behind me so I should now the basics.

I downloaded Xamarin Studio for Mac on the site, a dmg file was clicked and installation begun. I have gone through all steps and after problems with disk space (25 GB??) it was done.

Moving on to start Xamarin Studio and nothing happens. Absolutely nothing. I tried reboot my mac, I tried several times to start, but nothing.
(It was installed and required to enter my Admin password so it should have been installed as admin)

I use Yosemite 10.10.5 at the moment
I have Xcode installed version 7.1.1
I have Android SDK installed from before (but now also a new SDK :( )

When I read at the site there are not consistent information, at the requirements overview it says latest Xcode is required, on the actual table it is recommended. Anyone know if this is ACTUALLY my problem?

I have a problem to upgrade at this point as it can produce production problems for the deliveries I am about to do this week, at the same time I need to have Xamarin started.

Have anyone been running Xamarin with Xcode 7.1.1?? And build apps to iOS?

I was kind of expecting Xamarin Studio to at least start and let me know.

By the way I have been trying to find the answer here but cannot find anything, also at Google of course, let me know if you know a resource..

Hope I was enough specific

Answer (score 2):

1) Open `Console.app`, "Clear the Display" and launch `Xamarin Studio` and review the Messages for failures/issues

2) Open a shell (`Terminal` or `iTerm2`) and run `Xamarin Studio` and review any messages shown. A properly functioning `Xamarin Studio` launched to it's main window this way will not produce any messages in the shell.

```
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
```

3) Check the `Xamarin Studio` logs:

```
cd ~/Library/Logs/XamarinStudio-6.0/
rm *.log
/Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
```

*Review any `.log` files created*

#### Xamarin System Requirements:

- #### [macOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#macOS_Requirements)

Comment: In console I get this:  

2016-11-07 15:21:30,508 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.xamarin.xamarinstudio.276648[58329]) Service exited with abnormal code: 2
2016-11-07 15:21:31,210 locationd[89]: Location icon should now be in state 'Inactive'

Comment: Does not tell me to much, though. When I try to run Studio from term it claims it cannot fins Xamarcnstudio even though it is there AND I have permission

Comment: Last log in XamarinInstaller was saying all installed successful, prior to that I had a few tries with disk full, as I said above it takes up a lot of space. Never the less no other errors at all.

Comment: I will try to reinstall somehow because uninstall does not seem to be easy (way more files in there than uninstall doc says), trying now

Comment: @JörgenBuder In terms of running from the cmd line, does `file /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio` return anything? note: there is a space in the path, thus escape it with `\ `

Comment: @JörgenBuder In terms of reinstalling, you can start by just deleting the `Xamarin Studio.app` and leaving the Frameworks; Mono, Xamarin.XXXX, etc... alone. If that does not work, reinstall the `Mono Framework`.

Comment: Reinstalling, however in the system requirements of their homepage it states that minimum OS X version is 10.10, but they faulty claims that is El Capitan, but 10.10 is not El Capitan but Yosemite, which I have. Confusing. :( I only looked at the versin number and compared and thought I was good, but since I do not know what they mean I had to go with the fact that in the recommended column they say El Capitan and Sierra, but in the notes they state a different version and that logically should not say the same thing as in the recommended column. :(:(

Answer (score 1):

I'm running `El Captain 10.11.6` and what solved the problem to me was to follow @[SushiHangover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4984832/sushihangover)'s step 2 that is to open `Terminal` and run Xamarin from the cli, then I got this:

```
 $ /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/XamarinStudio
Cannot open assembly '/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/./XamarinStudio.exe': No such file or directory.
```

After that I googled it and read this [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=28573) thread that made me remove Xamarin Studio app:

```
$ rm -rf /Applications/Xamarin\ Studio.app
```

And and reinstall it from the original installer.
All worked fine after this. :)